# Turning product of multiple variable factors with constants into Big-O

Tags: notation, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I have a function which requires $(m+1)k(n+1)$ operations. How would I describe it in Big-O notation? I guess I need to keep the constants in $(m+1)$ and $(n+1)$ since they ensure that at best the complexity is $O(k)$ which is still not constant.

Comment: Does the input depend only on $k$ ?

Comment: @Peter No, they are all independent input variables.

Comment: Then, I think the correct notation would be $O(mkn)$

Comment: @Peter Why, do you think?

Comment: @MånsNilsson because to define the complexity, you need all three input variables. The number of operations scales with each of them linearly.

Comment: We can ignore the "$+1's$" if $m$ and $n$ are large.

Comment: @Peter But we don't know that.

Comment: But the text clearly indicates that $m,k,n$ are integers and that they can (in theory) be arbitary large. Without this assumption, we can only guess the complexity. Anyway, $O(kmn)$ is the worst possible complexity, since we know that the required number of operations does not grow more than linear in any variable.

Comment: If we assume that $m,k,n$ can be anything, fore example , bounded , then, the complexity could as well be $O(1)$

Answer (score -1):

If you have no information about $k, m, n$, then the best you can do is $O(kmn + km + kn + k)$. I'll argue that you can have a case where each of the terms in this sum could dominate the others:

1. If $m, n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$, then you have $O(1 + \sqrt{k} + \sqrt{k} + k) = O(k)$.
2. If $n = m = k = w(1)$, then it should be $O(kmn)$.
3. If $m > 1, n = \frac{1}{m}$, then you have $O(k + km + \frac{k}{m} + k) = O(km)$.
4. You can construct similar to point 3 for the result to be $O(kn)$.

Comment: This answer confuses me. The two users who commented on my original post agreed that $O(mkn)$ was the right way to go, since constants don't affect the asymptotic behavior in the long run (i.e. for big enough $m$ and $n$).

Comment: Case 2 of my answer covers the "big enough m and n" case. I totally agree that if m and n are big, then the answer is trivially O(mnk). I was only trying to cover for all possible edge cases. For instance, m could be a probability, in which case it could be something of the order $1/2^n$. Then, like you mentioned in your question, the + 1 cannot be ignored. Your question says nothing about what these parameters are, so my answer is intended to cover all possibilities. Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: If something requires m + 1 operations, you could say $O(m + 1)$, but you would drop the constant so it becomes $O(m)$, even if m isn't large. Doesn't the same rule apply in my case in general?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. For instance, if m = 1/n where n is large, then O(m + 1) should be O(1/n + 1) = O(1). It would be wrong to say O(m) in this case right?

Comment: Let me say something slightly different which I hope might be helpful. Normally, when you want to say O(max(a, b)), you can write it as O(a + b). You can surely see why. So when you are saying O(m + 1), you really want O(max(m, 1)). Now, in MOST cases, m would be much greater than 1, so like you said, you end up with O(m). But if m < 1, then you have O(1).

Comment: In the example I constructed m = 1/n with n large, so m is less than 1. That's why m would dominate. An example of where this could occur is if m is a probability or an error parameter. They are always <= 1.